# Cookie not being set in Safari, ios but works in ie, ff, chrome

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari

I was alerted that when items are placed in our shopping cart using safari/ios, they are not showing up.   The cart cookie is not being set.  It is set by a redirect page.  I saw the issue about safari not setting a cookie and redirecting, but if I take out the redirect, it is still not getting set.  Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload= function() {
 SetCookie('RORDERID','OECLICK*17180*39521',10);
setTimeout("redir()",100);}
function redir(){window.location = 'http://www.shopthethirdfloor.com/forward-to-ttf-cart.html';}
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {var today = new Date();var expire = new Date();
expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();}</script>
</head>
<body><br>If you are not redirected to the shopping cart, <a href="http://www.THESITE.com/forward-to-ttf-cart.html">click here</a></body></html>
```

I thought maybe the setTimeout would allow it to work, but if I take out the call to redir() it still does not set the cookie.

Any suggestions?

Additional notes:  I found a posting about this, and updated the code to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload= function() {
 setCookie2('RORDERID','OECLICK*17180*43',10,'','','');
//setTimeout("redir()",100);
}
function redir(){window.location = 'http://www.shopthethirdfloor.com/forward-to-ttf-cart.html';}
 function setCookie2 (name, value, nDays, path, domain, secure) {var today = new Date();var expires = new Date();
     expires.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
     var curCookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + (expires ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") + (path ? "; path=" + path : "") + (domain ? "; domain=" + domain : "") + (secure ? "secure" : "");
     document.cookie = curCookie;}</script>
</head>
<body><br>If you are not redirected to the shopping cart, <a href="http://www.thesitename.com/forward-to-ttf-cart.html">click here</a></body></html>
```

and it works, but still does not work on my site.  This code is being ran in an iframe from a different domain on my site.  The site is www.shopthethirdfloor.com.  If you go to products, select a product and add it to the cart, it does not add a cookie on safari, but does the other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, after a lot more digging and trial and error, it was the issue where safari would not set a cookie in an iframe cross domain.  I tried several suggestions on the web including here, but they either were not relevant or did not work (were old).  I found that I had 2 options.  The first, change the framed domain to be a sub domain of the parent window domain which I could have done, but would have needed to change umpteen links and the payment gateway which I did not want to do.  The second, took several steps, but works excellent is as follows:
The page that is trying to set the cookie checks if it is a safari browser and if it is, changes the window location to a php script on from the same domain as the browser passing the cookie in a get variable, this in turn changes the window location to an asp script from the iframe server sending it the cookie informtion which has the cookie setting code and after setting the cookie, loads the page for the the shopping cart. 
The key here is getting the cookie setting page that needs to set the cookie into the parent window and then load the new destination page.

This has a few steps, but works well.

Answer (score 1):

try to use HTML5 local storage concept to achieve cookie storage in safari browser

Default safari settings will be Cookies enable for trusted sites ,so you must enable the settings to enable cookie storage... TO overcome this issue you can use HTML5 local storage concept